# Time Intervals in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am very very new to Objective C and x-code. I just started learning it last week.  so sorry if the question is too simple.

I am doing a game more like a visual novel so its very simple and story board based app, but I have a question regarding displaying my choices. I want the choices to appear after my cut scene ends. is there any way I can add something like time-interval breaks so they only appear after certain time. can some one please guide me on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`NSTimer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0f 
                                 target:self
                               selector:@selector(displayChoiceTimerFired:)
                               userInfo:nil 
                                repeats:NO];
```

This will schedule a timer that will execute the `displayChoiceTimerFired:` method after 2 seconds. (The argument of that method is the timer itself.)

Or you can also use [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s `perform` methods:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayChoice:) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0f];
```

Comment: but I still add the objects in the UI builder normally correct but they will be displayed late. will it be better if I create another window?

Comment: Either create the new UI programmatically when the timer fires. Or make them hidden on Interface Builder and make then visible when the timer fires using `object.hidden = NO`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you are displaying your cut scenes, the safer way to display these UI elements would be to somehow trigger an action when your cut scene ends.  The problem with the NSTimer Implementation I can foresee is if, for whatever reason, your cut scene takes longer to play than your NSTimer interval is set to, then your UI Elements are displayed prematurely.  Just my two cents on a different, but what I believe to be a more elegant approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
[self performSelector:@selector(displayChoice:) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

You can use this method...where after delay is number of seconds